# How to migrate from MongoDB Compass Community version?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am new to **MongoDB** and installed **MongoDB Compass Community** version while installing **MongoDB**. I would like to migrate from Compass Community to Compass. I am having some hard time to follow the steps. 
   The compass version is **DMG** file, I converted it to **ZIP** and extracted the files from folder. I don't find any **.exe** to launch the Compass App. Not sure what I am missing here. 
[Files and folders I see after extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4UMc.png)

https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/upgrade/#upgrade-compass

Comment: The link is straight forward. I have followed it in recent past and migrated from Community edition. Which OS you use?

Comment: Hey RLD, I am using windows 10. I extracted files and folders from zip file. Don't understand what is wrong. Its written straight forward but not working for me.

Comment: The DMG (Apple Disk Image) download is for macOS / OS X. For Windows you need to download either the MSI (Microsoft Installer) or ZIP version of Compass by choosing the relevant "Windows 64-bit" option from the [Compass download page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is what I did for my migration from **MongoDB Compass Community** edition in Windows10.

1. I uninstalled the **MongoDB Compass Community** edition.
2. I downloaded and installed **MongoDB Compass**(Windows 64 bit MSI) from the url [Upgrade MongoDB Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/upgrade/#upgrade-compass)
3. I started new **MongoDB Compass** then.
4. Went to the following folder in File Explorer.

   C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\MongoDB Compass Community
5. Copied the folders *Connections*,     *FavoriteQueries*, *RecentQueries*, *SavedPipelines* from '**MongoDB Compass Community**' folder to '**MongoDB Compass**' folder which was in the same location.
6. Then I just stopped and restarted **MongoDB Compass**. I saw my old connections, favorites from Community edition.

So I will suggest you to clean up your **MongoDB Compass** first and follow the above steps for smooth migration.

Comment: Hey RLD, I uninstalled community version and download and install Compass all over again. It worked fine for me this time. Only other thing I did differently is first uninstalled community version. I suppose it shall not conflict but anyways, its all good now. Thank you very much for helping out, RLD.  Appreciate your time and help.